# What's the difference between tiny, huge and small in vim on MacPorts?

Tags: mac, command-line, vim, macports, vi

I'm trying to install `vim` via MacPorts. I found this port at http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/editors/vim/Portfile.

There are variants like `tiny`, `small` and `huge`. Is there any way to tell
which variant installs what features?

Comment: regardless, I'd recommend macvim for better mac os x integration, especially font rendering.

Answer (score 5):

Marcelo Cantos seems to have posted a nice link, but it's broken now.

Not sure if the contents are the same, but I found this link helpful:

http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vimfeat.html

Vim has several switches for features to include at compile time. The tiny, small, big and huge ones are actually pseudo switches that turn on collections of these features. The "tiny" switch basically gives you the bare minimum while huge gives you everything, modulo some X capabilities, etc.

Taken directly from that site:

> There are a lot of features available in Vim! Just bring up your vim
>   and do a `:version`; you'll probably see quite a few. How do these
>   features get selected? Well, some options are (de-)selected based on
>   the type of operating system you have, and some are (de-)selected
>   based on whether or not you want a gui (ie. gvim). You may choose
>   which options using the config script:
>
> example: `configure --enable-cscope --with-features=huge`
>
> The `--with-features` selector can take several words (tiny, small,
>   normal, big, or huge). This feature selector's effect is shown in the
>   table below. With a bit more effort you could tailor some features in
>   or out by modifying `<auto/config.h>` by hand, although some features do
>   need others to work right.

Comment: For exactly this reason (links going stale), please add a summary of the relevant contents of that link here.

Comment: The table shows no differences between the large and huge feature sets. Can you explain that?